# How to add auto complete json for dynamically generated textboxes in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to generate dynamic html textboxes in my aspx page and on these textboxes i want to add the value using autocomplete facility. I try my best to do so. I try almost every single question's answer of stackoverflow. But nothing is working here my script  which generate new textbox dynmacally

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {

            if (counter > 5) {
                alert("Limit Exceeds");
                return false;
            }

            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

//            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
//        '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
//        '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value=""  class="auto">');

            newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div class="fields-left"><label> Leaving from</label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="auto"/>  </div><div class="fields-right"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter+1 + '" class="auto"/> </div>');
           newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }

            counter--;

            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

        });


    });


</script>
```

Html code

```
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="fields" >
         <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
         </div>
    </div>
         <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'/>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'/>
          </div>
```

and I am trying this json code for fetching data for very first textbox that generate automatically. First I think for write this script for everytextbox which generate dynamically but this process will be so lengthy and wrong way to do this thing. But this is not working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  SearchText2();
              });
              function SearchText2() {
                  $("#textbox2").autocomplete({
                      source: function (request, response) {
                          $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              url: "Home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                              data: "{'code':'" + document.getElementById('textbox2').value + "'}",
                              dataType: "json",
                              success: function (data) {
                                  response(data.d);
                              },
                              error: function (result) {
                                  alert("Error");
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  });
              }
</script>
```

Please experts tell me why this json is working for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var counter = 2;
          $(document).ready(function () {

              $("#addButton").click(function () {
                  if (counter > 5) {
                      alert("Limit Exceeds");
                      return false;
                  }
                  var $wrap = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
                  var dynamichtml = '<div class="fields-left" id="divleft_' + counter + '"><label> Leaving from</label><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" class="auto"/>  </div><div class="fields-right" id="divright_' + counter + '"> <label> Going to</label>  <input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + 1 + '" class="auto"/> </div>';
                  $wrap.append(dynamichtml);
                  counter++;
              });

              $("#removeButton").click(function () {
                  if (counter == 1) {
                      alert("No more textbox to remove");
                      return false;
                  }

                  counter--;
                  $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divleft_" + counter).remove();
                  $("#TextBoxesGroup").find("#divright_" + counter).remove();


              });
              $(".auto").live("focus", function () {

                  $(this).autocomplete({
                      minLength: 2,
                      source: function (request, response) {
                          var textval = request.term; // $(this).val();
                          $.ajax({
                              url: "Home.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                              data: JSON.stringify({ code: textval }),
                              success: function (data) {
                                  response(data.d);
                              },
                              error: function (result) {
                                  alert("Error");
                              }
                          });
                      }, select: function (event, ui) {
                          return false;
                      }
                  });
              });
          });

</script>
       <style type="text/css">
      .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1" class="fields" >
         <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
         </div>
    </div>
         <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'/>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'/>
          </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Web
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string code)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
            list.Add("delhi");
            list.Add("noida");
            list.Add("gurgaon");
            return list.Where(i => i.StartsWith(code)).ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Please add js file as below
[image: add js file]

Comment: its give me two error 
1.  TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

2. TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Comment: 2 ReferenceError: inputName is not defined

Comment: Hi Azad which version of jquery you are using?  The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the on() method instead.

Comment: i am using these two links 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Azad I have update my answer.Please try the above code it works for me

Comment: now there is not any error but my list is not fetching no output i am getting

Comment: Ok when you debug the code the debugger comming to method GetAutoCompleteData or not?

Comment: i am sorry deepak can you please tell me how to check it I never check like this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52645/discussion-between-deepak-joshi-and-azad-chouhan)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use global variable say `data` to store the json response retirned for autocomplete.

and then use the same data to bind autocomplete after appending the contents.

```
  $('#newTextBoxDiv input').autocomplete(data);
```

Comment: can u please explain it how can i add global variable in jquery. I have no such a good knowledge about jquery

Comment: i mean javascript global variable in paying. and store the autocomplete json data in this variable in success function.

Comment: okk  but when i run this code this is not working why? This have to show error if there is no result its show nothing I check it in fiddler its give me nothing

Comment: can you share the fiddle??

Comment: i am sorry milind but I dnt know how to share it. I install fiddler application on my pc can you tell me what I have to do ?

Comment: can you tell me the variable value dat gets json. is it data or data.d from success function.

Comment: check this link i upload it online click on add button and try to enter value 

http://www.jcflightdeals.com/

Comment: can you alert the value data in ajax success??

Comment: got nothing... no alert :(

Comment: and what about data.d

Comment: Getting nothing I think this function is not working for these textboxes